# Get value from json arrayin java

Tags: java, json

I have a json array in java. Here is my json object.

```
   jsonString: {"user1":
                     [
                       {
                           "id":"11",
                            "address":"Roshan shore",
                            "phone":"9876543456",
                            "name":"Roshan"
                       }
                     ]
                }
```

I want to print the name.How can it possible in java without parsing?

Comment: What do you mean _"without parsing"_? _Something_ has to parse the JSON to extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object Mapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) for that. This will prepare the object or array of objects for you and you can later directly use it as a object

Comment: This might be a high-level answer, but `ObjectMapper` is a highly complex class and some minimal guidance on how to use it would make this a much better and usable answer.

Answer (score 0):

recommend Jackson JSON and fastjson